# call a function in angularjs controller from html and scope variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am a newbie in angularjs and need to know how to call a function which is define in controller from html in angularjs

I have wrote a code html

```
 First.html

<input type="text" ng-model="model.name" name="name" />

 Second.html

<p g-bind-template>{{model.familyname}}</p> // it displays the value
<div data-ng-controller="formCtrl" data-ng-init="init()">
      </div>
```

Is this way is correct or is there any other way to call a function. Also when init() is called scope variable is undefined

```
$scope.init = function () {
      alert($scope.model.name); // it displays undefined

    };
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: That is how you would call a function (before you edited your question), but typically you shouldn't need to use `ng-init`. Where have you defined a value for `$scope.model.name`? From what you have shown it's no wonder that it is undefined. That is what would be expected.

Comment: @Lex, I have edited my question

Comment: @Lex in one html I am getting name and on next html i am displaying it on html it display the name on html but in controller it displays undefined

Answer (score 0):

`ngInit` directive is meant to run an expression and assign a scope variable. There is a nice warning in the docs about using it:

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Instead of using ngInit, I would suggest running the function in the controller:

```
controllerFunction($scope) {
    $scope.someFunction = someboundfunction;
    //etc...

    activate();

    function activate() {
        // do some activation stuff
    }

    function someboundfunction() {
        //...
    }
}
```

The coding style of placing bindable members at the top, keeps me from going crazy when writing big controllers that have activation logic. It's [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y033), if you're interested in that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep things you want to use inside this controller to make it worked.

```js
angular.module('TestApp', []);

angular.module('TestApp')
  .controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.model = {
      name: 'Default name'
    };

    $scope.alertName = function(where) {        
      alert(where + ': ' + $scope.model.name);
    };

    $window.onload = function() { 
      // will be called after ng-init
      $scope.alertName('On Load'); 
    };
    
    // call it directly from controller
    $scope.alertName('From controller');
  }]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="formCtrl" ng-init="alertName('Ng-init')">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="model.name" />
      <button ng-click="alertName()">Alert this name</button>
      <p>{{ model.name }}</p> 
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually in next html I need model.name and then call a function on html load and on that function I need that name thats why it is displaying undefined

Comment: @Java_NewBie You can combine multiple htmls (with relevant controllers) under one parent controller with your necessary variables in it. After that, these variables will be accessible from html in the way you want.

Comment: How to call a function written in controller form html. Lets say on page load

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the magical world of AngularJS. Angular could be a little overwhelming at first, but don't give up. You're going in the right direction.

A few suggestions for the code you have written -
- You need to encapsulate your complete code inside the controller to be able to process data to and from it.
- I am assuming you already have initialized your app using ng-app or some other ng-someName 
- Since, ng-init is used to initialize a parameter/method, you don't need to mention it as such in your code. $scope will take care of it automatically (It's cool, right!)

So your code would look like something below after implementing the suggestions above -
    //html code

{{ Username }}

```
//angular.js
 app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Username = '';
 });
```

Let the magic begin! ;)